# why can I not pass a null node but I can pass a null value

Tags: java, binary-tree

I finished [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-binary-trees/#/description) leetcode question with this answer

```
public TreeNode mergeTrees(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
        // if both are null, assign merge tree to null
        if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return null;
        // if t1 or t2 is null, add 0
        int sum = (t1 == null ? 0 : t1.val) + (t2 == null ? 0 : t2.val);
        TreeNode tSum = new TreeNode(sum); // declare locally to prevent overwriting
        tSum.right = mergeTrees(t1.right, t2.right);
        tSum.left = mergeTrees(t1.left, t2.left);
        return tSum;
    }
```

and it throws a NullPointerException when t1 or t2 is equal to null. But when I looked up the correct answer, it's only slightly different.

```
public TreeNode mergeTrees(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
        // if both are null, assign merge tree to null
        if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return null;
        // if t1 or t2 is null, add 0
        int sum = (t1 == null ? 0 : t1.val) + (t2 == null ? 0 : t2.val);
        TreeNode tSum = new TreeNode(sum); // declare locally to prevent overwriting
        // pass null if either == null to avoid nullpointerexception
        tSum.right = mergeTrees(t1 == null ? null : t1.right, t2 == null ? null : t2.right);
        tSum.left = mergeTrees(t1 == null ? null : t1.left, t2 == null ? null : t2.left);
        return tSum;
    }
```

Where instead of passing the left or right node value, it passes null.

**Why does java throw a nullpointer exception in the first case only, when both parameters seem to equal null?**

Comment: The logic of both versions will allow at least one incoming `TreeNode` to be `null`.  Then, when making the recursive calls, there is the possibility of deferencing a `null` object.  The second version covers its bases by checking for this.

Comment: It's more than "slightly" different. The correct version checks each reference variable for `null` before dereferencing it. That's majorly different, not slightly. It's the difference between "Aah" and "Aaaagh!" Big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the .right method on a null object (t1 or t2). Calling a method on a null object will cause a null exception.

The title is incorrect - you are not passing a null node, you are passing a null node's child.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This helps a lot!